# Is there a reason for heavy doors in hotels?

Tags: hotels

Almost every hotel I've been in has had an enormously heavy door that bangs when it closes.  Now, I've been to many homes, offices, and retail outlets with solid doors that have a *definite* pull-back to ensure closure.  But only hotels seem to have that enormous 'slam' that resonates through the hallways.

Is there something I'm missing or is it all in my head.  **Why do hotel doors have to be so cumbersome?**  Maybe there are standards for 'star'-qualifications.

**EDIT for clarification** (as requested): Hotel room doors, almost universally, is what I am referring to.  Even with sound-dampening hallways, they are almost always very cumbersome.  I understand fire-proofing, but that can be done with less noise.  Is there a reason beyond that?

Comment: I've seen that in residential homes as well, in particular apartment blocks.

Comment: I'm not sure the noise is really related only to the weight of the door, the door closer force but have an influence, to make sure the door actually closes despite the lock in the way (and the weight of the door related to its fireproof nature). In many places where you have door closers, the door does not actually lock by itself, there's actually not even a full contact in many cases, and/or the door will be much lighter. Also it doesn't matter (too) much if many of those doors don't actually close, while an unclosed hotel room door is an actual problem.

Comment: Almost every hotel I've been in has not had doors that produce an enormous slam. The fire doors have a soft-close mechanism.

Comment: Note that the generally long and empty hallways will carry sound further than a furnished room; if you're comparing hotel door slams to home door slams. Not a full answer, but a consideration.

Comment: Yes. They're fire doors, designed to protect you in case a fire breaks out elsewhere in the building, and to reassure you against the anxiety that such a thing might occur - so that you might sleep more easily at night. Oh, the irony.

Comment: What I don't get is why I'm seemingly the only person alive on the planet who actually closes doors behind him with his hands. Why let it slam? Grr!

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close - I'm very curious if there is a policy for fire doors to be very loud and heavy, I suspect there is a policy somewhere about the weight beyond just being fireproof (or maybe there is a cost-savings) and that is cool, I am just asking what it might be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to make it sound like you are angry and frustrated if you happen to live in the room with that door. ;)

Comment: @OrangeDog yap you are right, so the slamming is marketed as an exclusive feature but in practice the only thing the service provider does is to disable the slow-close :D

Comment: Is *Almost every hotel I've been in* international? In small and large cities?

Comment: I have never, ever, encountered a door in a hotel such as the doors described.   Maybe it's in a certain country or something?

Comment: I have stayed in a lot of hotels in a lot of countries, and have almost never encountered doors that would slam if left...but in the two cases the doors didn't have soft close, I closed them myself anyway! This question should remain closed as it is entirely opinion based!

Answer (score 103):

They're fire doors.  They have a fire rating, that describes how long they can survive a fire burning on either side of them.  This fire rating means a fire in a room will give safe passage in the hallway outside for a significant period of time (perhaps an hour or more), or allow a fire to rage outside in the corridor while people in the room have a period of safety.  They are required by fire codes in various countries.

Similarly, larger apartment buildings in many countries have similar fire code requirements.

You'll notice doors on stairways and in other locations have similar traits, and for the same reasons.  These doors must always be closed, or must have some sort of automatic mechanism that will close them automatically in the event that a fire alarm is triggered.

Comment: That’s not a reason for them to be designed to make a banging noise that wakes everyone in a two blocks radius. I have seen fire=proof heavy doors that close nearly silently.

Comment: This is a good piece of the puzzle, so +1, but as @Aganju states, it can't be the full reason.  We have fire doors in my office - in a very regulated country for this - and they don't sound ridiculously loud.

Comment: @Aganju : I suspect you are just more sensitive to the noise of a hotel door than a similar door in an office block.

Comment: @Mikey: I think it may be a matter of circumstance. Your office is likely more noisy than the hotel at night, so comparatively the bang may not sound so loud. It might also be that your office interior architect was more careful and the door closes more silently... I'm always amazed at how noisy hotels are, being a quiet-loving person.

Comment: Mechanisms that prevent a door-slam usually make a door potentially less safe and more expensive.

Comment: @Daniel Former security personnel here: Not only do fire doors have to be certified but also door closers. In fact, it is against regulation to *not* have a door closer for a fire door. I'm guessing that closers which are "good enough" for closing in emergencies are also louder as a consequence.

Comment: Another extension to this would be that the extra "slam" at the end of the door closer's travel could be to overcome resistance placed by the door latch mechanism, which would be required to make sure the door closes properly and doesn't end up ajar. This would also then be a security thing, if you were walking out of your hotel room, the door didn't close properly behind you and someone was to just walk in and raid your room I'd imagine the hotel wouldn't want to foot the bill for replacing your stuff.

Comment: @errantlinguist No, even the cheap closers have adjustment screws to set the damping force for two or three phases of the closing motion (wide-open to part open, part-open to nearly closed, and for the final bit of travel just before full closure).  Overly heavy doors, or slammy doors, have simply been poorly adjusted.  It's the kind of thing that would take someone 15 minutes to fix with a screwdriver or allan key.

Comment: Fire doors need, ideally, to close securely, and to close quickly.  I imagine one could make them close securely, quickly and quietly, but it would probably be expensive.  It's all what someone wants to pay for.

Comment: @RobbG but you can design the latch mechanism to make it nearly effortless to close the door. Then the only thing to overcome is airpressure as you seal off the opening.

Comment: @ratchetfreak true, it a well designed building with good communication between departments this would be the case, but it's also possible the door hardware was chosen by construction contractors to be the cheapest to purchase x-hundred of, and the closing mechanisms were later specified and added by an engineer with little to no communication between departments. This is often the case with larger building projects. It's also possible for a very nice door latch to be made almost useless by a badly installed door, resulting in the need to slam it to get it to close properly.

Comment: @Aganju (and everyone else) Most door closers are adjustable and potentially could be made not to slam. **Unfortunately**, most maintenance crews are understaffed, overworked, and undertrained and spending literally hours tweaking a door closer after finding the manual for it to know how to properly set the **two** different damping areas properly is just not a high enough priority, especially if you might fail a fire inspection if you overdo it in the wrong direction. I've been down this road regarding a particular door at a job and eventually just gave up on it.

Comment: If your question is about the noise, why did you type "heavy" instead of "loud"?  Your comments suggest people aren't answering the question you meant instead of the question you typed.

Answer (score 53):

[Jim MacKenzie is right](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/109452/6387) that they are fire doors, which is why they are so heavy, but that doesn't address the reason that other heavy doors don't seem to make as much noise.

I believe the greater noise actually has to do with the acoustics of the hotel hallway - almost always a bare unadorned long and narrow space - the perfect shape for echos and reverberations. Offices often have wide open areas such as "cube farms" nearby, they often have many doors on the hallway open at once, and they are much more likely to have people in them whose bodies and clothes deaden the noise.

As proof, I offer two apartment buildings in my neighborhood. One is built similarly to most hotels - long narrow (and slightly curved, but that doesn't make a difference) hallways - and the other has shorter hallways with groups of apartments accessible by different entrances. They both use extremely similar building materials and fire doors, but the first one echoes significantly (you can hear a door close from 20-30 apartments away on the other side of the building) and the second one you can hear your neighbor's door but not the next apartment past your neighbor.

Answer (score 11):

The banging is often due to automatic closing devices, which are required on fire doors in many places, and tend to be set to ensure locking.

These are adjustable in two sections: the main part of the range of movement and the last few degrees.  They often come set to close most of the range quite slowly, then to shut the last bit quite quickly to ensure the door closes tightly and latches securely.  While it's possible to adjust them to close the last little bit slowly, this isn't desirable from the point of view of security, as the door may rest on the latch and not lock.  Realistically these closers are unpacked and fitted, but not adjusted from the factory settings unless the door doesn't shut properly, because that takes time (a few minutes per door IME), and time is money.

I have adjusted the one on a hotel room, because the door closed very slowly and let all the heat into the cold corridor before banging shut.  I know what's possible from having set these things up in labs, where the vibration of the door banging would be a problem.

But of course it tends to be the other rooms that disturb you, and you can't do a lot about them.  Even earplugs are of limited use for the low frequencies that carry a lot of the power in the noise.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, they're fire doors.

But they are also *commercial* doors.  Any commercial door is going to feel heavy, since it's built out of solid wood or steel.  Contrast with a family residence interior door, made of <= 1/8" veneer luaun plywood (already light) and [cardboard honeycomb](http://www.koopdoors.ca/honeycomb-doors/) or foam.  There's no substantial wood except where hinges and knobs go.  They can be fine doors if the honeycomb is glued to the veneer, but they are utterly unfit for hotel-room door service.  You could kick right through them.

[image]

*This is residential "normal". Hotel doors are the opposite of this.*

Doorknobs too - a commercial class 1 lever doorknob can weigh 5 pounds even without the card scanner.  Whereas a residential privacy knob set is a few ounces.

The door latch mechanism is also heavy and commercial, and so needs a bit of an "action" to close with surety.

Part of this is driven by ADA requirements (slow closer, lever handles, positive latching) and fire codes too - the tuckback levers are to prevent snagging fire hoses or a fireman's gear and knocking him off his feet.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a noise problem solved by having heavy doors. A normal door like used inside houses would provide poor sound isolation creating privacy problems. Also in the hotel room you would hear people walking and talking in the hallway, even if they were not doing that in a loud way.

Answer (score 0):

They are called "Fire Doors". They're heavy so that they would be able to stop a fire coming into or spreading out of your room. The safety aspect outweighs the noise issue.